# Efficient way to find top K products given two lists

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

Given two lists of equal length `N`, I want to find the `K` largest products that can be made by multiplying an element from each list. For example, if

```
> A = [7, 9, 4, 1, 6]
> B = [8, 1, 3, 10, 7]
> K = 3
```

the result is `[90, 72, 70]` or `[9*10, 9*8, 7*10]`, found by

```
> sorted([x*y for x in A for y in B], reverse=True)[:K]
[90, 72, 70]
```

Is there a more efficient algorithm that doesn't involve multiplying out all `N^2` pairs?

Comment: You do not need to multiply every elements of the lists. If you need K values, you can just retrieve first K max values of each lists and multiply each pair. But I think there is an even more optimized solution.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, the first step is to sort both lists `A` and `B` in descending order (or just the K largest of both lists). Then, all the max K products will sit in a roughly triangular area in the top-left corner, the max product being `A[0]*B[0]`. In other words, if `A[i]*B[j]` is in the top K, then so must be both `A[i-1]*B[j]` and `A[i]*B[j-1]` (assuming `i, j > 0`).

Thus, you can start in the top-left corner and then use a [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) to expand both the "lower" and the "right" neighbor of the current element and put those onto the heap, too, until you have all the K elements you need. Or start with all the K largest elements of A paired with the largest from B already on the heap and only expand in one direction.

Example in Python, using the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module, but the same will work in almost any other language. Note that we are adding *negative* products to the heap as the heap will be sorted smallest-first.

```py
def top_k_prod(A, B, k):
    A = heapq.nlargest(k, A)
    B = heapq.nlargest(k, B)
    result = []
    heap = [(-A[i] * B[0], i, 0) for i in range(len(A))]
    while heap and len(result) < k:
        p, a, b = heapq.heappop(heap)
        result.append(-p)
        if b < len(B)-1:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (-A[a] * B[b+1], a, b+1))
    return result
```

Example:

```py
import random
A = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)]
B = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)]
K = 20
result = top_k_prod(A, B, K)
test = sorted([x*y for x in A for y in B], reverse=True)[:K]
print(result)
# [9900, 9702, 9603, 9600, 9504, 9408, 9405, 9405, 9400, 9400, 9312, 9306, 9300, 9216, 9212, 9212, 9207, 9200, 9120, 9120]
print(result == test)
# True
```

The complexity should be about `O(NlogN + KlogK)` for sorting `A` and `B` and then *about* `K` iterations with heap-operations in the loop. Each cell in the triangular "target" region will only be expanded once from its left neighbor, and cells added to the heap but not used are also limited to K (one in each "row"), giving a maximum of 2*K elements inspected.

Comment: This can be improved to `O(N + KlogK + K)` by using `numpy.partition(A,n-k)[-k:]` to find the K largest values in O(N), and only then sorting them.

Comment: Can also use `heapq.nlargest(k, A)` to find the largest K values in order in `O(KlogK)`.

Comment: @wowserx Maybe, but originally the question was not even tagged as Python but just a generic algorithm question, so I wanted to keep it generic. You can use a heap in (almost) any language.

Comment: Right, and you can use a heap in exactly the same way: O(N) heapify, then K heappops for O(N + KlogK + K). I'm saying the algorithmic performance is better if you only sort the K largest elements, instead of calling `A = sorted(A, reverse=True)` right away.

Answer (score 0):

Practical solution:

Find largest `K` elements from list A and `K` largest elements from list B by using [partial_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) (this is a well-known modification of quick sort, and I am sure python has the same in its library). Largest products formed by these new lists are also the largest products of the original lists. Then use max-heap (priority queue) to find `K` largest products from new lists.

Answer (score 0):

If we would find out K max values from both the lists, we would have the max `K` products from both the lists.

I would suggest two approaches to find out K max values:

1. If `K <<< N` ( `K` in 10s and `N` in millions  ) 
   Here you have couple of options.

   - You can use [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) K times for both the lists. That would take `O(N*K)`
   - K iterations of either [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) or [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). You would have `K` max values at either at the beginning or at the end of the array depending on the type of implementation. Even that would be `O(N*K)`

> Note that because `K <<< N` you can say that `O(N*K)` is almost `O(N)`

2. `K` can be as same as `N`

   - In this case, The best bet would be to just sort both the lists using [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) or [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). That would be `O(N*lgN)`

Comment: "because K <<< N you can say that O(N * K) is almost O(N)" Well, by that reasoning you could also say that sorting the entire list in O(nlogn) is almost O(n). And I agree, for mot practical purposes, it probably is. But then, why not just sort the entire list? In fact, with K=10 and N=1000000, nlogn is still smaller than n*k.

Comment: Also, even if you have the max K values from both lists, you still have to find the max K of those K² pairs/products of numbers. This part is not really addressed.